# Firewall configuration for Windows 7 and the Greenbow VPN client

Tags: vpn, firewall, windows-7, ports

I'm looking for the correct firewall/router settings to get the Greenbow VPN client to work with Windows 7 64-bit.

It never seems to get past phase 1 in the connection process.

Comment: serverfault is better .

Comment: Sorry realized after I posted this that there are better places. 

BTW The answer is ports 500 and 4500 need to be opened inbound and outbound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports 500 and 4500 need to be opened inbound and outbound; the client will then work.